# How can I know the last date I used insert trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, ssms, system-views

I need to get the last `datetime` I used a particular `insert trigger` only by `system view` etc.

Pay attention that the date modified of the table isn't correct answer for my question because it includes also table update dates.

If you think that I need to improve my question please leave comment for me

Thank you

Comment: The only way to do this 100% accurately is to add logging to your trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This method is only reliable when you are in full recovery model and have log backups..

```
select [Begin Time],    * 
from sys.fn_dblog(null,null) where 
AllocUnitName='yourtablename'
```

I don't think this is captured any where unless you have Auditing enabled.

Comment: And even this is only somewhat reliable because it would record the last time an insert happened, if the trigger was disabled you could get false positives. Still a good answer.